ServiceM8 API to find availability and send booking link via SMS
Having issues accessing the job activities data in make.com. I can access any data if I use the jobs endpoint.
My goal: I want to figure out what the availability is for my client so that I can get the AI voice caller to provide callers with the accurate available time slots and book them in. It should honestly be an easy task, but anyhow.
So, decided to try it out in Python rather.
Firstly, has anyone had this experience in Make.com?
Secondly, I'm thinking it would probably be a more streamlined approach to just send the client the booking link via text so they can do the booking themselves while on the phone. (https://support.servicem8.com/hc/en-us/articles/200272744-How-to-schedule-jobs)
Does anyone have advice regarding how I can get this done via the api?
I have tried to access the job activities and other api endpoints in Make.com but only the jobs one works when I use the ServiceM8 api call module.
